# weather api is not working in chainlink function playground

Tags: chainlink

I tried to get weather information using weather API in Chainlink function, but getting error. I tried to run that Chainlink function playground.[image]

Comment: Please replace the picture of code with actual code to make it easier for others to provide assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your request was failing due to `AxiosError: Network Error`.

You should refactor your code like this (notice the `https` change):

```js
// Execute the API request (Promise)
const apiResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=640e6535b8274f8595264603241101&q=Sydney&aqi=no`
});

// Should return Sydney
return Functions.encodeString(apiResponse.data.location.name)
```

If you leave the Output Type to the default `string`, this returns "Sydney" in Functions Playground. You should be able to try this on your own by clicking the following URL, https://functions.chain.link/playground/32e7b13f-5da0-4443-9f02-3ac3b67c6a42, generated from the Chainlink Functions Playground's Share Code feature.

Also, in future iterations, it is highly advisable to store your API key as a secret value.